# Bash script with logger

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, logging

I'm trying to write a simple script for MYSQL data base backup with logger function. But i'm stuck on logger, i know that it should be very simple to do, but my mind is already out. 
I'm using in script next string:

```
mysqldump -u username -p'pass' --all-databases > /var/backup/mysqlbck.sql
```

My target is to log to syslog with logger by 2 different facility.

- local0.warn - should send log if database can't backup
- local0.info - should send log with success log.

I've tried to add `logger -p local.warn 2>> /to/file/`
also tried with `-s` parameter but it's not what I need and to be honest I don't see the point to use logger when there is present STDERR `2>>` .

Comment: You want to log to a file *and* to syslog? And you want stdout and stderr sent logged with different syslog priorities?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only log via logger:

```
mysqldump ...
ret=$?
if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "mysqldump: success" | logger -p local0.warn
else
  echo "mysqldump: error" | logger -p local0.info
fi
```

Log to a file and via logger:

```
mysqldump ...
ret=$?
if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "mysqldump: success" | tee -a /path/to/file | logger -p local0.warn
else
  echo "mysqldump: error" | tee -a /path/to/file | logger -p local0.info
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cyrus.. 
Cheers.